# Saving Images with image_saver with timestamp

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

i use linux 16.04 with ros kinetic and gazebo 7.0. I have a simulated turtlebot from the turtlebot package. I want to save the rgb images with timestamp like i can save the pcd files with timestamp.

At the moment i am using this to get the image:

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

when i run this i get something like: left0000.jpg . So is it possible to get the images with timestamp ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283724/saving-images-with-image_saver-with-timestamp/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
I'm guessing you use `image_saver`, not `image_view`, correct?

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
yeah right copied code wrong i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a look at the code ([image_saver.cpp](https://github.com/wkentaro/image_pipeline/blob/e1bd3a058a9d566718475f7557b98050bf304060/image_view/src/nodes/image_saver.cpp)) it doesn't look like including the timestamp in the filename is supported right now.

The `video_recorder` node does support adding a timestamp since [ros-perception/image_pipeline#203](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/203). Perhaps that approach could be ported to `image_saver.cpp`, but note that `image_saver` uses `boost::format`.

<del>Note btw that `sensor_msgs/Image` does not have a header, so any timestamp added would be the time at which the message is received, not the stamp at which it was published.</del>

Edit: I misremembered, `sensor_msgs/Image` does have a `Header`, so the stamp should be there (if set by the publishing node of course). See [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
Is there a way to get rgb images with timestamp when it was published? I need the correct rgb image that fits to the pcd file. I trying to make some machine learning task for my robot thats why i need it

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
I am struggeling now how to go on right. Would it be correct to modify the image_saver.cpp that it is possible to save images with timestamp ? So i need to access to the header of the topic correct ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
Yes, you could try to see how you'd access that information. You could consider passing the timestamp of the incoming `Image` msg to the `saveImage(..)` method that is used by both callbacks in `image_saver.cpp`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
If you get this to work it would be +100 if you'd then submit a PR against `perception/image_pipeline` to add this to the 'official' node.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
found this solution for video_recorder :

[timestamp video recorder](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/203/commits/667018392a4e24870553fa65e3a8eb6f78142bc7#diff-47907d20f886b97368970221b312f95a)

will this work similar for image_saver?

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
tried it on a python node where i save pics and it works, so it should also work for image_saver i think

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
That is what I linked to in my answer, it's the changes introduced in PR `image_pipeline#203`. That could work, but it uses `ros::Time::now()`, which is not what you want. You'd need to change that to use the stamp in the header of the received `Image` msg.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
Thank u so much, i think i found a solution that works. Now i have pcd files and image files with the same timestamp. I post the code in a seperate answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So with the help of gvdhoorn i found a solution:

First of all i  found code for saving my images i take the code from this tutorial:

[Image saver Ros](https://gist.github.com/rethink-imcmahon/77a1a4d5506258f3dc1f#file-ros_image_saver-py)

then i added some lines for the timestamp so it looked like:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# Copyright (c) 2015, Rethink Robotics, Inc.

# Using this CvBridge Tutorial for converting
# ROS images to OpenCV2 images
# http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

# Using this OpenCV2 tutorial for saving Images:
# http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

# rospy for the subscriber
import rospy
# ROS Image message
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
# ROS Image message -> OpenCV2 image converter
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
# OpenCV2 for saving an image
import cv2

# Instantiate CvBridge
bridge = CvBridge()

def image_callback(msg):
    print("Received an image!")
    try:
        # Convert your ROS Image message to OpenCV2
        cv2_img = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
        print(e)
    else:
        # Save your OpenCV2 image as a jpeg 
        time = msg.header.stamp
        cv2.imwrite(''+str(time)+'.jpeg', cv2_img)
        rospy.sleep(1)

def main():
    rospy.init_node('image_listener')
    # Define your image topic
    image_topic = "/camera/rgb/image_raw"
    # Set up your subscriber and define its callback
    rospy.Subscriber(image_topic, Image, image_callback)
    # Spin until ctrl + c
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) with karma: 206 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
Great to hear that you got something to work, but realistically this is really a work-around, as `image_saver` itself does not support what you were asking.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
I need this for machine learning, my thesis is about a simulated turtlebot which do some image recognition with tensorflow. So i needed rgb images and pcd files with the same time stamp. So it works semi well, i need the same clock speed like pcl publishes the pcd files. But i think i'll get i work

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
:) I wasn't criticising anything, just observing that you wrote that you found a *solution*. Your question is about getting `image_saver` to store files with a timestamp, but that is not possible (right now). So strictly speaking there is no solution to your question. That's what I was pointing out.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
Yeah thats correct, maybe they will add this in the future.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-27**:
There is a much higher chance of that happening if you either:

- add it yourself and submit it
- open an enhancement issue over at [ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues)

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-30**:
@baumboon hey did you habe a github account or a e-mail address for questions, i don't want to spam here everything with my questions